# Validation logic for Mobile Number Column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, data-validation

I am creating a validation script and need help with mobile number validation logic with below details.  Mobile number must be:

- 10 digits in length.
- Cannot begin with a 1 or a 0 (For example:1144684679 or 04468-4679
- Cannot contain all the same digit.  For example: 5555555555

I am using PATINDEX for this but could not come up with the proper result.

Comment: Does this have to be done strictly in T-SQL, or do you have the option of performing this validation in another language (a C# component in an SSIS package or a full application, for example), or via a platform like Master Data Services or even a service/external API? How do you intend to handle people (like me) whose phone number isn't a direct line, but a 10-digit number plus a local extension once you connect to my company's phone system?

Comment: Are non-numeric characters allowed?  Like dashes?

Comment: Are you _sure_ there will never be [international phone numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers)? It's usually much easier to do application level validation instead of pushing it into the database.

Comment: In the UK all mobile numbers begin with a zero. What locale are these rules valid for?

Comment: Simply because a value matches an expected format does not make it "valid" (as in, it is an number that is currently in service in some undefined location / country).

Comment: @deep kachhawa.  You will want to use Martin's answer over the one I posted (now deleted).  That Scalar function involved looping on each character individually which Martins answer avoids.  I imagine his answer will run much, much faster than mine which will be very important if this validation is used with any degree of regularity.

Comment: Thanks @KirkSaunders for your valuble input.

Answer (score 1):

I seriously doubt the real world utility of the specified validation rules but a reasonably concise way of validating them is below.

```
SELECT PhoneNumber,
       Valid = CASE
                 WHEN PhoneNumber LIKE CONCAT('[23456789]', REPLICATE('[0123456789]', 9))
                      AND PhoneNumber LIKE CONCAT('%[^', LEFT(PhoneNumber, 1), ']%')
                   THEN 'valid'
                 ELSE 'invalid'
               END
FROM   (VALUES ('0123456789'), 
               ('1144684679'), 
               ('5555555555'), 
               ('5555555554'), 
               ('9876543210'), 
               ('9876')) PhoneNumbers(PhoneNumber)
```

---

```
+-------------+---------+
| PhoneNumber |  Valid  |
+-------------+---------+
|  0123456789 | invalid |
|  1144684679 | invalid |
|  5555555555 | invalid |
|  5555555554 | valid   |
|  9876543210 | valid   |
|        9876 | invalid |
+-------------+---------+
```

Comment: Martin.  This answer is amazing by the way.  I think understand what the first part of the validation is doing.  In the 2nd part `LIKE CONCAT('%[^', LEFT(PhoneNumber, 1), ']%')` the validation to make sure it isn't the same number for every character?  I am not super familiar with utilizing REGEX.

Comment: Thanks - and yes that's what it is doing. If the first character is `5` the expression will be `LIKE '%[^5]%'` which means that the phonenumber needs to contain a character that is not `5`. Could also use `PhoneNumber <> REPLICATE(LEFT(PhoneNumber,1), 10)`

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith I have checked this and its working fine for me .

Comment: Hey @MartinSmith what about below logic as it is giving me same output 
  SELECT * 
FROM DemoContact
WHERE NOT PATINDEX('%[^01][^01][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',Contact)=0 
AND Contact <> REPLICATE(LEFT(Contact,1),10)         (DemoContact is a table which has contact column,)

Comment: `^01` just excludes 0 and 1, this means that it will allow non numbers which isn't what you need...